# Plotting a symmetric function with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been trying to plot the following function defined by ln(2x²-1)/(x²-1), which should yield a symmetric graph. When plotting the right hand side of the graph I did nothing but reflect the domain along the y-axis but the result is not a symmetric graph. What is going on?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!20] (-2.9,-2.9) grid (2.9,2.9);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[-latex,thick] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above]{$y$};     
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1,1,2}
    \draw (\x,.1)--(\x,-.1) node[below] {\x};   
    \foreach \y in {-2,-1,1,2}
    \draw (-.1,\y)--(.1,\y) node[right] {\y};
    \draw[thick,blue!50!black, domain=-3:-1.15,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{(ln(2\x*\x-1))/(\x*\x-1)});
%%% Something is wrong with the following plot %%%
    \draw[thick,blue!50!black, domain=1.15:3,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{(ln(2\x*\x-1))/(\x*\x-1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: TikZ does not have implicit multiply. I do not know why `2\x` does not return an error.

Comment: Did you try by using explicit multiplication between `2` and `\x*\x`?

Comment: @hpekristiansen `2\x` does not return an error because TeX is a macro language and `\x` is subject to normal expansion. For example when `\x` holds `1` then `2\x` will expand to `21` which is a totally valid number. The same gotcha applies to `\x^2` where when `\x` holds `-2` it will expand to `-2^2` which evaluates to `-4`. This is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you just have to use explicit multiplication to avoid "false" expansions of your figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!20] (-2.9,-2.9) grid (2.9,2.9);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[-latex,thick] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above]{$y$};     
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1,1,2}
    \draw (\x,.1)--(\x,-.1) node[below] {\x};   
    \foreach \y in {-2,-1,1,2}
    \draw (-.1,\y)--(.1,\y) node[right] {\y};
    \draw[thick,blue!50!black, domain=-3:-1.15,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{(ln(2*\x*\x-1))/(\x*\x-1)});
%%% Something is wrong with the following plot %%%
    \draw[thick,blue!50!black, domain=1.15:3,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{(ln(2*\x*\x-1))/(\x*\x-1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: symplotfunction]